# Why do I only have a single view in NVIDIA Control Panel?

Tags: windows-vista

I have recently bought an alienware M17x Vista 64 bit DDR3 8 GB
Video Card = 2 x 280M Geforce total 2GB Memory

My NVIDIA control panel version is Geforce 280M version 179.85

Can someone help me know why i only have single view? it states which view is better

but in the option, i can only see single view (nothing else)

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Single View? Mean like having a second Monitor? Mind taking a screenshot of the dialog you mean and upload it at Imageshack?

Comment: yeah ok the link is 

http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/7718/nvidiat.jpg

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh...I see. But it's odd. I know, a long shot, but I'd try to upgrade the drivers to the recent ones, maybe they've added the support for multiple displays with the latest version.

Also, I stumpled upon [this](http://www.notebookforums.com/thread141540.html) discussion...posting number #9 describes this behaviour, with the solution to turn SLI off.

Answer (score 1):

ok i found it thank u all...

the problem was the driver , i just needed to update it ...

but its weird its a new laptop 4 days old (today) how come the driver is not latest ?

anyway thanks again guys !

Comment: Even the latest drivers can have unknown bugs

Comment: That's because the software-set was assembled some time ago. ;) Most of the vendors take a snapshot of each driver, test this version and leave updating to the clients.

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, with older drivers (Pre 180.00?) you cannot have more than one monitor with SkI enabled, unless you are cloning the screen. The nwest drivers support multiple screens with SLI enabld.